# How to sped up the below Excel VBA macro function?

Tags: performance, excel, macros, vba

This function is slowing down my whole system.

```
Sub Projection(RegionStr As String, Noofmonths As Integer, Cc1 As String, Cc2 As String)
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks, wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim cycle1_mon, cycle1_yr, cycle2_yr, src1, src2, cycle2_mon As String
    Dim month, factor, fc_start, missed_month, miss, count As Integer
    Dim fc_mon, inc, diffr, row_num_var3, y1, m1, m2, diffa, currentRow As Integer
    Dim i_cycle1_mon, i_cycle2_mon, i_cycle1_yr, i_cycle2_yr As Integer
'looping variables
    Dim loop_var, row_num_var1, row_num_var2 As Integer
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
'Extract Month and year for user provided START-DATE & END-DATE
    cycle1_mon = Mid(Cc1, 5, 2)
    cycle1_yr = Left(Cc1, 4)
    cycle2_yr = Left(Cc2, 4)
    cycle2_mon = Mid(Cc2, 5, 2)
    i_cycle1_mon = CInt(cycle1_mon)
    i_cycle1_yr = CInt(cycle1_yr)
    i_cycle2_yr = CInt(cycle2_yr)
    i_cycle2_mon = CInt(cycle2_mon)

    strtd_with_err_flg = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY_TBL")
    wks.Select
    If Err Then
        gdivolume.Status.Caption = "Missing Tab -> Summary_Tbl"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        gdivolume.Status.Caption = "Updating Forecast Rows "
    End If
    On Error GoTo Err_Exit:
    wks.cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
'cleaning already existing data in Forecast sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast").Visible = True
    Set wks2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")
    wks2.Select
    gdivolume.Status.Caption = "Cleaning the Forecast Tab"
    wks2.cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToRight
    currentRow = 1

    For row_num_var2 = 2 To wks.UsedRange.Rows.count
        src1 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("A" & row_num_var2)
        src2 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("A" & row_num_var2 + 1)
        m1 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2)
        m2 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 + 1)
'once Summary_tab records are over then exit loop
        If src1 = "" Then Exit For

        currentRow = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count
        If row_num_var2 = 2 Then
            month = CInt(m1)
            Call start_miss(row_num_var2, month, i_cycle1_mon, i_cycle1_yr, wks2, wkb, src1)
        End If
        currentRow = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
        If src1 = src2 Then
            If strtd_with_err_flg And row_num_var2 = 2 Then
                currentRow = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
            End If
            wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num_var2).EntireRow.Copy
            wks2.range("A" & currentRow).Select
            wks2.Paste
            'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & currentRow).Select
            'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            'Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("A" & row_num_var2 & ":F" & row_num_var2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num_var2)
            'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & currentRow & ":F" & currentRow).Select
            wks2.range("E" & currentRow & ":F" & currentRow).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'assigning SLR factor as 10 for the first month in the actuals range for all source code
            If i_cycle1_mon = wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value Then
               'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = 10
                wks2.range("G" & currentRow).Value = 10
            End If
            If i_cycle1_mon < wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value Then
                diffa = wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value - i_cycle1_mon
                'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = (diffa + 1) * 10
                 wks2.range("G" & currentRow).Value = (diffa + 1) * 10

                If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value <= 0 Then
                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value + 120
                    wks2.range("G" & currentRow).Value = wks2.range("G" & currentRow).Value + 120
                End If
            ElseIf i_cycle1_mon > wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value Then
                diffa = i_cycle1_mon - wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value
                'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = ((diffa + 1) * 10) + wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("G" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value
                wks2.range("G" & currentRow).Value = ((diffa + 1) * 10) + wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("G" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value
            End If
            m1 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2)
            y1 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("F" & row_num_var2)
            m2 = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 + 1)
'check if the month values are continuous in the Summary_tbl tab and identify rows which are missed in between
            If m2 <> CInt(m1) + 1 Then
'if new rows has to be inserted after december month
                If m1 = 12 Then
                    If m2 < m1 Then
                        missed_month = m2 - 1
                            If missed_month > 0 Then
'insert the missed rows and set the values for all columns in the newly inserted missed rows
                                For loop_var = 1 To missed_month
                                    Dim row_num As Integer
                                    row_num = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
                                    range("A" & row_num).EntireRow.Insert
                                    wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num - 1).EntireRow.Copy
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num).Select
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
                                     wks2.range("A" & row_num).Select
                                     wks2.Paste

                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("B" & row_num).Value = 0
                                    wks2.range("B" & row_num).Value = 0
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num).Value = loop_var
                                   wks2.range("E" & row_num).Value = loop_var
                                    'If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num).Value < 10 Then
                                    If wks2.range("E" & row_num).Value < 10 Then
                                        'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num).Value
                                        wks2.range("E" & row_num).Value = 0 & wks2.range("E" & row_num).Value
                                    End If
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num).Select
                                    wks2.range("A" & row_num).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num - 1).Value
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("D" & row_num).Value = "ACTUAL PROD VOLUME"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("C" & row_num).Value = "DUMMY"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num - 1).Value + (10)
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num).Select
                                    'Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num).Value = y1 + 1
                                    wks2.range("A" & row_num).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num - 1).Value
                                   wks2.range("D" & row_num).Value = "ACTUAL PROD VOLUME"
                                    wks2.range("C" & row_num).Value = "DUMMY"
                                    wks2.range("G" & row_num).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num - 1).Value + (10)
                                    wks2.range("F" & row_num).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wks2.range("F" & row_num).Value = y1 + 1
                                Next loop_var
                            End If
                    End If
                End If
'if new rows has to be inserted after any month other than december
                If m1 <> 12 Then
                    If m1 < m2 Then
                        missed_month = m2 - m1 - 1
                            If missed_month > 0 Then
                                For loop_var = 1 To missed_month
                                    Dim row_num1 As Integer
                                    row_num1 = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
                                    range("A" & row_num1).EntireRow.Insert
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num1 - 1).EntireRow.Copy
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num1).Select
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
'                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("B" & row_num1).Value = 0
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Select
'                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1 - 1).Value + (1)
                                    wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num1 - 1).EntireRow.Copy
                                    wks2.range("A" & row_num1).Select
                                    wks2.Paste
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wks2.range("B" & row_num1).Value = 0
                                    wks2.range("E" & row_num1).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wks2.range("E" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1 - 1).Value + (1)


'                                        If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Value < 10 Then
'                                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Value
'                                        End If
                                        If wks2.range("E" & row_num1).Value < 10 Then
                                            wks2.range("E" & row_num1).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num1).Value
                                        End If

                                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num1).Select
                                   wks2.range("A" & row_num1).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                        If Len(src1) = 2 Then
                                            'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num1).Value = "0" & src1
                                            wks2.range("A" & row_num1).Value = "0" & src1
                                        Else
                                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num1).Value = src1
                                            wks2.range("A" & row_num1).Value = src1
                                        End If
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("D" & row_num1).Value = "ACTUAL PROD VOLUME"
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("C" & row_num1).Value = "DUMMY"
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num1 - 1).Value + (10)
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num1).Select
'                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num1 - 1).Value

                                     wks2.range("D" & row_num1).Value = "ACTUAL PROD VOLUME"
                                    wks2.range("C" & row_num1).Value = "DUMMY"
                                    wks2.range("G" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num1 - 1).Value + (10)
                                    wks2.range("F" & row_num1).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wks2.range("F" & row_num1).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num1 - 1).Value
                                Next loop_var
                            End If
                    End If
                    If m1 > m2 Then
                        miss = m1 - m2
                        missed_month = 12 - miss - 1
                            If missed_month > 0 Then
                                For loop_var = 1 To missed_month
                                    Dim row_num2 As Integer
                                    Dim mon, yr As Integer
                                    row_num2 = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
                                    range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Insert
                                    wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num2 - 1).EntireRow.Copy
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num2).Select
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("B" & row_num2).Value = 0
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num2).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num2).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num2 - 1).Value + (10)
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num2).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                        If Len(src1) = 2 Then
                                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num2).Value = "0" & src1
                                        Else
                                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num2).Value = src1
                                        End If
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("D" & row_num2).Value = "ACTUAL PROD VOLUME"
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("C" & row_num2).Value = "DUMMY"
                                    mon = m1 + loop_var
                                    yr = i_cycle1_yr
                                        If mon > 12 Then
                                            mon = mon - 12
                                            yr = i_cycle2_yr
                                        End If
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num2).Value = mon
                                        If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num2).Value < 10 Then
                                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num2).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num2).Value
                                        End If
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num2).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num2).Value = yr
                                Next loop_var
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        inc = 1
'if we have reached the last record containing data in Summary_tbl tab
        If src2 = "" Then
            wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num_var2).EntireRow.Copy
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & currentRow).Select
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & currentRow & ":F" & currentRow).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                If wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2) > wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value Then
                    diffa = wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value - wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow - 1).Value + (diffa * 10)
                        If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value <= 0 Then
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value + 120
                        End If
                End If
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num_var2).Value
        End If
'if we are reading the next set of data corresponding to new source code
        If src1 <> src2 Then
            wkb.Sheets("Summary_Tbl").Rows(row_num_var2).EntireRow.Copy
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & currentRow).Select
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Paste
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            'Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("A" & row_num_var2 & ":F" & row_num_var2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num_var2)
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & currentRow & ":F" & currentRow).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            month = wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2)
            If wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2) > wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value Then
                diffa = wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2).Value - wkb.Sheets("Summary_tbl").range("E" & row_num_var2 - 1).Value
                wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow - 1).Value + (10)
                    If wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value <= 0 Then
                        wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value = wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & currentRow).Value + 120
                    End If
            End If
            Call end_miss(row_num_var2, month, i_cycle2_mon, i_cycle2_yr, wks2, wkb, src1)
            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").Select
'after filling all the actuals data range for each source code as the range specified
'by user, we need to insert forecast rows
            row_num_var3 = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
                For row_num_var1 = row_num_var3 To row_num_var3 + Noofmonths - 1
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num_var1).Select
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("A" & row_num_var1).Value = Sheets("Summary_Tbl").range("A" & row_num_var2).Value
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("D" & row_num_var1).Value = "PROD SOURCE - FORECASTED VOLUME "
                    fc_mon = i_cycle2_mon + inc
                    'wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value = fc_mon
                        If fc_mon < 10 Then
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value
                        End If
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value = fc_mon
                    inc = inc + 1
                        If i_cycle2_mon < fc_mon Then
                            diffr = fc_mon - i_cycle2_mon
                            factor = 10 * diffr
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("G" & row_num_var1).Value = 130 + factor
                        End If
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num_var1).Select
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
                    wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num_var1).Value = i_cycle2_yr
                        If fc_mon > 12 Then
                            fc_mon = fc_mon - 12
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value = fc_mon
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("F" & row_num_var1).Value = i_cycle2_yr + 1
                        End If
                        If fc_mon < 10 Then
                            wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value = 0 & wkb.Sheets("Forecast").range("E" & row_num_var1).Value
                        End If
                Next row_num_var1
        row_num_var3 = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.count + 2
        Dim fcst As Integer
            For fcst = row_num_var3 - Noofmonths To row_num_var3 - 1
                If fcst = row_num_var3 - Noofmonths Then
                    Call SLR_max(row_num_var3 - Noofmonths, Noofmonths - 1)
                    Call AverageDeviation(row_num_var3 - Noofmonths, Noofmonths - 1)
                    Call Forecast(row_num_var3 - Noofmonths, Noofmonths - 1)
                ElseIf fcst <> row_num_var3 - Noofmonths Then
                    Call SLR_max(fcst, Noofmonths - 1)
                    Call Forecast(fcst, Noofmonths - 1)
                End If
            Next fcst
            month = CInt(m2)
            Call start_miss(row_num_var2, month, i_cycle1_mon, i_cycle1_yr, wks2, wkb, src2)
        End If
    Next row_num_var2
    Call CreateHeader
    Call Delete_EntireColumn
    Call Trim_Format
    Call pivot_generate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast").Visible = False
    gdivolume.Forecast.BackColor = vbGreen
    gdivolume.RefreshPivot.Enabled = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
Exit Sub
Err_Exit:
    Debug.Print "Err: -> " & Err.Description
    gdivolume.Forecast.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place Option Explicit at the top of the page before the Sub code starts.

After the Sub line move Application.ScreenUpdating = False there.

Before the End Sub move Application.ScreenUpdating = True there.

For all integer variables convert to CLngPtr.